# How to apply show to any type in haskell?

Tags: haskell

i am trying to write a function to print all elements of any type in a list (including my own data type), but i find that not all types are an instance of show.  is there anyway that can make haskell know that type a is/is not an instance of show? or i can simple turn every type into string.  here is my code.

```hs
displayList :: [a] -> IO()
displayList (x : xs)
    | not (null xs) = (show x) ++ displayList xs
    | otherwise = show x ++ show xs
```

Comment: I see @dfeuer has answered your main question, but there is another issue here - it looks like you want your recursive function, when corrected, to return a `String` but its type signature, as well as your description, suggests you instead want an IO action. In the latter case you want to look at `print` rather than `show`. And while it's easy enough to do it with direct recursion, you can define it in one line using the `mapM_` function.

Answer (score 7):

You can indicate in your type signature that the type must be an instance of `Show`.

```
displayList :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
```

Your recursion looks a bit off though. I would start off with this skeleton:

```
displayList [] = _base
displayList (x : xs) = _rec
```

You shouldn't need any guards, and you shouldn't need to use `null`.

Note: showing lists certain ways requires two base cases:

```
displayList [] = _base0
displayList [x] = _base1
displayList (x : xs) = _rec
```

Based on your code so far, I don't *think* you need that here, but since you didn't show an example of what you want, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: what i dont want is the comma between elements in list, and i want this function word for all types. like we i do displayList [1,2,3], it shows like 1 2 3. my problem is that there are always some types that are nor an instance of show, just like int.

Comment: @李灏泽, I don't understand what you mean. If the type isn't an instance of `Show`, you can't show it unless you have some other function on hand to do the showing. Can you give some examples of what you really want?